# как воткнуть картинку в div, чтобы она не вылезала за края div

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sec-consult">
            <div class="one_third col-lg-4">
                <div class="s_line"></div>
                <div class="sec-con-img">
                    <img src="img/expert.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: `max-width: 100%;` для `img` не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать максимальную ширину **картинки**, т.е.

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.sec-con-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="sec-consult">
        <div class="one_third col-xs-4">
          <div class="s_line"></div>
          <div class="sec-con-img">
            <img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого в Bootstrap есть класс `img-responsive`, благодаря которому изображения занимают всю ширину родительского элемента, не выходя за его границы.

По сути, он состоит из стилей:

```
max-width: 100%; height: auto; display: block;
```

Для вашего случая достаточно дополнить код картинки этим классом:

```
<img src="img/expert.png" class="img-responsive"/>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: чего только не перепробовано - вылазит картинка, зараза

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/AHKwBXH4MO - все работает, возможно, у вас где-то что-то не подключено.

Answer (score 0):

Если изображение находится в `div`, то в CSS нужно тому самому `div` задать параметр `overflow: hidden`:

HTML

```
<div class="comp">
<img class="road" src="png.png" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.comp {
overflow:hidden;
}
```